# jquerymobile + phonegap external page inside div / iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, iframe, cordova

im trying to embed external webpages (facebook pages / twitter) inside jqm iframe but the iframe didn't load.

```
<div data-role="content" >  
<iframe>http://m.facebook.com/pages</iframe>
</div>
```

i already put *.facebook.com in phonegap whitelist.

```
<access origin="http://*.facebook.com" browserOnly="true"/>
```

been looking for solution for a week now without any result.
i wonder if anybody can give me another method, because this is not working.

update: it seems i can inject random php page inside iframe, but cannot display facebook or twitter. do i need to use fb / twitter api?

ps. im not doing a fbconnect stuff, just display the mobile version of a page.

another thing that i did try:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#twit' ,function(){

    var ref = window.open(encodeURI('http://apache.org'), '_blank', 'location=yes');
    // relative document
    ref = window.open('next.html', '_self');

        $("#twitcont").append(ref);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PhoneGap external page using InAppBrowser

```
var ref = window.open(your_url, 'random_string', 'location=no');

ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {

});
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
     console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);

});
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) plugin, also replace your access rule by the following one just for testing:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

then you can start loading the page directly using:

```
var ref = window.open('http://m.facebook.com/pages', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Comment: done, but i don't know where to start with the example, there's to many.

Comment: you can follow examples in phonegap website I mentioned in my answer

Comment: yes i followed your suggestion, try to append inside div but not working. $("#twitcont").append(ref);

Comment: It will open a page with your url not on specific div

Answer (score 0):

After adding an InAppBrowser in place of the iframe I was using before, I eventually tried an iframe again, and the iframe now works without jumping over to the phone's browser, as it was doing before, and the iframe works consistently in both iOS and Android.

2 things changed from the time that iframes were broken to when they started working:

I upgraded to Cordova 2.5
I started dynamically creating/adding the iframe to the page using jquery, rather than just unhiding an already-existing iframe, as I was doing initially:

$('').appendTo('body'); .

Comment: could you be more specific? like appending facebook to id.

Comment: you want to open or display in iframe

Comment: in iframe or div, anything inside the content div. basicly i want to embed the page, not open it.

Comment: it have a issue or restriction..try to open apple site , i m sure it will open .

Answer (score 0):

NSURLErrorCancelled Returned when an asynchronous load is canceled. A Web Kit framework delegate will receive this error when it performs a cancel operation on a loading resource. Note that an NSURLConnection or NSURLDownload delegate will not receive this error if the download is canceled. Available in OS X v10.2 and later. Declared in NSURLError.h.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add URL in src attribute

```
<iframe src="http://m.facebook.com/pages"></iframe>
```

Comment: it seems loading random page is ok, but facebook and twitter page cannot. whats wrong?